# Explaining the Solution Explorer ASP.NET Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Can somebody provide me link from where i can understand what these things are actually meant?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [this page of the tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create-the-project) for your answer. I strongly recommend reading it through.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this page, and the itens in the left menu:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26k97dbc(v=vs.90).aspx